# Django - Filter QuerySet in models.py

Tags: python, django

Is is possible to make queries from django models?

I have 2 models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    def copies_available(self):
        pass
```

and

```
class BookCopy(models.Model):
    ...
    book_category = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='copies')
    issued_to = models.ForeignKey(EndUser, related_name='issued_books', null=True, blank=True)
```

I want `copies_available()` to return the number of `BookCopy` intances of that `Book` whose `issued_to` is `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    def copied_available(self):
        return self.copies.filter(issued_to__isnull=True).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes just set `limit_choices_to` in the ForeignKey. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

"A dictionary of lookup arguments and values (see Making queries) that limit the available admin or ModelForm choices for this object. Use this with functions from the Python datetime module to limit choices of objects by date. For example:"

```
limit_choices_to = {'pub_date__lte': datetime.date.today}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this a couple years ago, so it may have changed a little bit:

You nee to create a BookManager class, and put the functionality there. Then assign the manager to your Book model's object variable, like this:

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):

    def copied_available(self):

        queryset = BookCopy.objects.filter(book_category=self.id).filter(issued_to is not None)

        return queryset.count()

class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = BookManager()
```

So in your template, you can do something like:

```
<p> Copies: {{ thebook.copied_available }}</p>
```

Comment: you should not overwrite djangos default model manager while filtering results, it may lead to undesired results (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#writing-correct-managers-for-use-in-automatic-manager-instances)